# LTC mining is better than BTC mining?

Tags: litecoin, mining-profitability, gpu, cpu

I've got a notebook with these specifics:

- CPU: AMD Phenom X3 II N830 3.14GHz (3-Core)
- GPU: ATI Radeon HD 5650 1GB

Mining 1 LTC is faster than mining 1 BTC? How I estimate the times for BTC and LTC? 
Overall, I get more money with LTC mining or with BTC mining?

Comment: I would not recommend mining with a laptop period.  Heat becomes and issue quickly and they are not designed to be run like this.  LTC will give you a better return that BTC on this kind of hardware.  BTC really requires an ASIC and even most of the older ones are being obsoleted daily.  TL;DR if you want to mine buy a desktop and GPUS for LTC or invest many thousands into ASIC's that may or may not pay for themselves by the time you get one in your hands.

Comment: Yes, using your CPU and GPU mining for 1 LTC is faster than mining 1 BTC. Nobody mining BTC by CPU/GPU computation power, which might be measured in MegaHash/s, because ASIC can easily reach TeraHash/s or GigaHash/s with less power consumption or better energy efficiency. However, considering current LTC difficult, if your hashrate is 100KH/s, than you will got 0.0345 LTC per day. It would almost requires 1 month to gain 1 LTC.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, there are custom miners for Bitcoin. These use customised hardware (ASICs) and thus GPU mining is not profitable. However, this custom hardware does not exist for Litecoin and most other altcoins (based on scrypt). Thus, you might still be able to make money GPU mining Litecoin this way.

Unless you have customised hardware, forget about Bitcoin mining.

The other contributors are correct though - doing this on a laptop is probably not a good idea anyway, but you'll still make more doing Litecoin than Bitcoin.

Answer (score 1):

Just because mining one litecoin is faster does not mean anything. I can mine 50000 Dodgecoin in the time I can get one bitcoin but my bitcoin is actually worth something. You need to determine for yourself what currencies you see being useful in a few years from now as well as how much you see each growing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check which crypto-currency gives you the more money should you mine it, and this depends on your hash-pawer, that coin's network's difficulty as well as the avg. value it has in the markets.

You can guide yourself checking these sites:

- http://dustcoin.com
- http://coinwarz.com
- http://wheretomine.com/

Or use a "multipool" that automatically switches from mining one coin to the other depending on which one is the most profitable. Mined coins are sold immediately and you get paid in bitcoins. I've only used this one so far, seems good:

http://middlecoin2.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what to mine (there is much much more than bitcoin and litecoin), have a look at:

http://wheretomine.com/

or

http://litecoinminingcalculator.com/ (for detailed info about litecoins.)